# Blocking consumer of PipeReader.AsStream()

Tags: .net, pipe

I was playing around with the [Pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipe?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) class in .NET to hook up a producer and consumer API which only accept Streams.

The consumer API has a basic implementation that assumes, during a [Stream.Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Stream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_), if the number of bytes read is less than the `Count` parameter it must have reached the end stream.

When delivering the consumer a `PipeReader.AsStream()`, if the consumer reads outperform the producers writes, then the consumer fails to read the full pipe, per the prior logic.

I ran up a basic bit of test code to confirm

```f#
    open System.IO.Pipelines
    
    let pipe = Pipe()
    
    let producer (stream: Stream) =
        let srcStream = 
            [0..100] 
            |> Seq.fold (fun state num -> sprintf "%s,%i" state num) "" 
            |> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes 
            |> MemoryStream
        let mutable read = -1
        let buff: byte[] = Array.zeroCreate 10
        while read <> 0 do
            read <- srcStream.Read(buff, 0, 10)
            Thread.Sleep 50 //simulate a slow producer
            stream.Write(buff, 0, read)
            
    let consumer (stream: Stream) =
        let mutable read = 100
        let mutable offset = 0
        let buff: byte[] = Array.zeroCreate 1000
        while read = 100 do
            read <- stream.Read(buff, offset, 100)
            offset <- offset+read
        buff |> Encoding.UTF8.GetString |> printfn "%s" //only prints 0,1,2,3,4 not -> 100!
        
    Thread(fun () -> producer <| pipe.Writer.AsStream()).Start()
    consumer <| pipe.Reader.AsStream()
```

The only way I could think of to block the consumer was to wrap the `PipeReader` in a custom `Stream` class, and implement the necessary blocking logic in the `Read()` override.

I notice there are some [backpressure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines) mechanisms for the writer, but is there anything built in to help "throttle" a `Stream` only consumer?